# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).chosen(...).on is not a function

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-chosen

I have used a JQuery chosen function on a `<select>` element on UI which populates the `<option>` values from the database via ajax call.

```
<select id="assetClass" data-placeholder="Choose an Asset Class..."
    class="chosen-select" multiple style="width: 200px;" tabindex="1">
<option value=""></option>
```

I am writing a jquery code in a js file which will **console.log** or **alert** whichever element is selected or deselected from the `<select>`

```
$(".chosen-select").chosen().on("change", function(event, params) {

  if (params.selected) {
    //  $("#status").text('The option: ' + params.selected + ' was selected.');
     console.log(params.selected);

  }
  if (params.deselected) {
  //   $("#status").text('The option: ' + params.deselected + ' was deselected.');
      console.log(params.deselected);
  }});
```

But the problem is when i load the page, I get below error

**Uncaught TypeError: $(...).chosen(...).on is not a function**

Other stackoverflow answers suggests adding (jQuery); at the end as below.

```
;(function($){
    // your code
})(jQuery);
```

But still the problem exists.

Comment: use $.noconfilct(); function

Comment: .chosen is not jQuery method, it seems to be a plugin, have you load the plugin?

Comment: @Esko If he didn't load the plugin it would say that `chosen` is not a function, but it says that `on` is not a function. So the problem is with what `chosen()` returns.

Comment: Your code seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/ep1d6uyr/ The error would make sense if the `chosen()` method did not return a jQuery object, but it does.

Comment: Actually the code works fine If i execute it https://jsfiddle.net/iamravikk/Legxf0vk/5/ But when i integrate the same code in my project, it gives that error in the console.

Comment: Thank you everyone for you answers. I finally found out the issue is with jquery. I was using jquery-1.6.2.min.js in my project and it does not support `on` function. The only way to use was bind which was a bit difficult. Finally I upgraded to jquery-1.7.min.js and finally I am not getting any errors.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I had to add `import "chosen-js"` to make it work.

Comment: and from where to import

Answer (score 0):

You have to import 'chosen-js' after importing jQuery

```
const $ = import 'jquery'  
import 'chosen-js'
```

Comment: Probably I'm doing this wrong but for me this only results in `Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`